# CTE Function in SQL Server 2008 for Time Period Enrollment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Presently I have the following table structure in Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

I have a table which has Course Enrollments:

```
CourseEnrollment
(
  EnrollmentId guid  //autogenerated primary key,
  StartDate datetime,
  EndDate datetime,
  CourseId guid, 
  TotalCreditValue int,
  NominalDuration int
)
```

- I basically need to write a CTE function to split all the enrollments into months. When everything is split into months.
- Every time a Student has completed 1 months worth of training they earn credits i.e. TotalCreditValue/NominalDuration.
- For example:  Let's say we have an Enrollment which began in 1st Jan 2013 and ended in 3rd November 2013.
- On the 1st of Feb 2013, the student will have gained a full months worth of Credit.
- Now October 2013, the student will have also gained a full months worth of Credit for their enrollment, but I would also need to know how long they have been enrolled for i.e. the 'Age' of the enrollment.
- I basically need to write a CTE function which splits the CreditValues into Months with their corresponding 'Age' (i.e. how long the student has been enrolled for).
- In 1st of Feb 2013, the student would gain a month worth of credit, and the Age would be 0. But for the next completed month, the Age would be 1.
- They would only gain credits when a 'full' month of training has been completed.

I would then Push the CTE into a Table with the following structure:

```
CreditsToMonths 
( 
   IdCreditToMonths guid PrimaryKey,  //autogenerated
   Month int, 
   Age int,
   CreditValue int, 
   EnrollmentId guid 
)
```

I am currently using a `WHILE` loop with SQL and it's pretty expensive speed wise.

Here is something I have written before but I have a feeling I am including months which should not be included:

```
;with CTE AS
(
    Select EnrollmentId, StartDate As [Date]
    From CourseEnrollments   

    UNION ALL

    Select CTE.EnrollmentId,CTE.[Date]+1 As [Date]
    From CourseEnrollments   As T
    Inner Join CTE On CTE.EnrollmentId=T.EnrollmentId
    where CTE.[Date]<ISNULL(T.EndDate, GETDATE())
)
select EnrollmentId,Convert(varchar,[Date],103) As [Date]
from CTE
order by EnrollmentId
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: That sounds like a great plan. Off you go.

Comment: On a side-note, why are you using `guid` and not `IDENTITY` for example?

Comment: This is something that I wasn't too sure about. Currently the pre-existing data structures all appear to be using GUID, however I can see why this might be a burden for CreditsToMonths

Comment: So you're updating the TotalCreditValue in the CourseEnrollment table as each month goes by?  Do you want to see a running total of credits, or just the credits earned that month?  For example, on March 1st the age would be 1, but would the credits be 1 or 2?  On April 1st the age would be 2, but would the credits be 1 or 3?

Comment: It would just be for that month, not a running total.

Comment: Basically CreditsToMonths stores the amount of credits earned for each month that goes by. The credits earned = (TotalCreditValue for Course)/(NominalDuration for Course)

Comment: And NominalDuration is just the number of months between the StartDate and EndDate?

Comment: No. NominalDuration is basically the nominated course duration. So for example, a course might be called 'English Language' and it typically goes for 2 years. Sometimes students take longer to finish it, other times students do an year then drop out. It's just the nominated amount e.g. 2 years in this example. If they take longer to finish it, they earn more credits than the TotalCreditValue, if they withdraw before they earn less. So for example, they drop out 1 year early, only half the TotalCredits are earned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a jumping off point. fnGenerate_Integers returns a table with integers from param1 to param2.  Ways to do that... [LINK](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)

```
WITH Dates AS
(
    SELECT n.n, DATEADD(MONTH, n.n, StartDate) StartDate, DATEADD(MONTH, n.n + 1, StartDate) EndDate
    FROM (VALUES (1)) a(a)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(StartDate) StartDate, MAX(EndDate) EndDate FROM CourseEnrollment) m
        CROSS APPLY dbo.fnGenerate_Integers(0, DATEDIFF(Month, m.StartDate, m.EndDate)) n
)
SELECT ce.*, d.StartDate
FROM CourseEnrollment ce
    INNER JOIN Dates d ON ce.StartDate <= d.StartDate 
        AND ce.EndDate >= d.EndDate
```

Comment: Jarad's Number table is basically the source of my dbo.fnGenerate_Integers. I agree with keeping something like that in your database.

Comment: I'm going to run this and see how I go. Will report back in a couple of hours!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works brilliantly. My queries are about 200x faster now :) Thank- you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might get you started.

Create a numbers table.  This is just a table with a single column of sequential integers.  Just leave this table in your database (it comes in handy).

```
create table Numbers(Number int)
insert Numbers
SELECT TOP 10000 row_number() over(order by t1.number) -1 as N
FROM master..spt_values t1 
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
```

Here's the actual query:

```
select c.EnrollmentId, 
--CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(c.StartDate)-1), c.StartDate),101) gives you the 1st of the month of StartDate
DATEADD(m, n.Number + 1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(c.StartDate)-1), c.StartDate),101)) EnrollmentMonth,
n.Number Age,
--Only assign credits if it isn't a partial month
case when
  DATEDIFF(d, 
           DATEADD(m, n.Number, c.StartDate), 
           DATEADD(m, n.Number + 1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(c.StartDate)-1), c.StartDate),101))) >= 30
    or          
            DATEDIFF(d,              
            DATEADD(m, n.Number + 1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(c.StartDate)-1), c.StartDate),101)),
            c.EndDate) >= 30 then 1 else 0 end Credits

from Numbers n
join CourseEnrollment c on n.Number + 1 < DATEDIFF(m, c.StartDate, c.EndDate)
```

It looks ugly, but that's because of all the date manipulations.  By joining to the Numbers table, you get a row for each month (and it also figures the Age for you).

I don't know how you want to handle partial months (e.g. if the course ends on 11/3, what is the age for the month of 11/1?), but I think you should be able to use this general idea and tweak things to get them how you want them.

Here's a link to a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92f60/6).